# How to construct ZonedDateTime from an Instant and a time string?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

Given an object of `Instant`, a `time string` representing the time at a specific `ZoneId`, How to construct a `ZonedDateTime` object with the date part (year, month, day) from the instant at the given `ZoneId` and the time part from the given `time string`?

For example:

Given an object of Instant of value **1437404400000** (equivalent to **20-07-2015 15:00 UTC**), a time string **21:00**, and an object of `ZoneId` representing **Europe/London**, I want to construct an object of `ZonedDateTime` equivalent to **20-07-2015 21:00 Europe/London**.

Comment: How do you want the date to be affected by the time, if at all?

Comment: I want to extract the date part from the instant and the time part from the string. The time string represents the time at the specified time zone.

Comment: But an instant doesn't *have* a date - it's just a point in time, which would be on different dates depending on the time zone. See my post for two options, basically...

Comment: Yes, an instant doesn't have a date. I want to extract the date from it at the specified time zone and add the time from the time string (which is also at the specified time zone).

Comment: Right, that isn't clear from the question - see my answer for two alternative interpretations, and their consequences.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Righto - I've simplified my answer to just the one then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to parse the time string to a `LocalTime` first, then you can adjust a `ZonedDateTime` from the `Instant` with the zone, and then apply the time. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.US);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeText, formatter);
ZonedDateTime zoned = instant.atZone(zoneId)
                             .with(time);
```

Answer (score 9):

Create the instant and determine the date in UTC of that instant:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1437404400000L);
LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();

// or if you want the date in the time zone at that instant:

ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
LocalDate date = instant.atZone(tz).toLocalDate();
```

Parse the time:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("21:00");
```

Create a ZoneDateTime from the LocalDate and the LocalTime at the desired ZoneId:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(date, time, tz);
```

As pointed out by Jon you need to decide which date you want as the date in UTC may be different from the date in the given time zone at that instant.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer and the one written by assylias, there is another simple way to achieve what you want.

You can use [`ZonedDateTime#ofInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) to obtain a `ZonedDateTime` from the `Instant` and then adjust it to the given time using [`ZonedDateTime#with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-).

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1437404400000L), ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
    .with(LocalTime.parse("21:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)))
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wLh1Oi)

**Expanded**:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1437404400000L);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("21:00", formatter);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId).with(time);
```

Learn about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.